# Using S-mosfets to construct AND, do the nand gates need to have high resistance?

Tags: homework

In order for the out to receive most of the current, are R3 and R5 selected large to prevent waste of current to the ground? This is an AB or !(!A or !B) from agarwal lang.

[image]

Comment: You need to balance the "waste of current to ground" against the risetime you want to have on the drains of the transistors.

Comment: @DavidTweed, so here just to produce that logic we are wasting $V^2/(R3+R4+R5) right$?

Comment: @DaveTweed So you make these R's big, and you have another problem that the mosfets threshold won't match the 0 and 1 input values. That is, the mosfets below R4 now have to respond to very little current.

Comment: MOSFETs don't respond to current, they respond to voltage. But they have a significant gate capacitance that needs to be charged/discharged.